# Assigning different messages to same .getBytes()

Tags: java

Right now, my User Interface has **4 EditText object**.
**Row 1** , **Row 2**, **Row 3** and **Row 4**

I started sending data:

On **Row 1**, the string is *4569*

On **Row 2**, the string is *369*

When I try get the length by using `msg.getBytes().length` I only get 4 which is the length of the Row 1 string = 4569. But in real fact, I sent 2 rows of data which is 2 EditText(FILLED with Data).

But how do I get the length of **Row 2**, **Row 3** and **Row 4**?

**buttonConnect.setOnClickListener (Sends the data to the bluetooth device)**

```
buttonConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                        "Please enable bluetooth first.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            // Need API=14
            else if (!socket.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(bluetoothtest.this,
                            "Connecting! Please wait.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else {
                try {
                    sendMessageHandle(contentRow1.getText().toString());
                    sendMessageHandle(contentRow2.getText().toString());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

**sendMessageHandle Method:**

```
private void sendMessageHandle(String msg) throws InterruptedException {

    final byte ANIMATION_MODE=1;
    final byte PICTURE_MODE=2;
    final byte TEXT_MODE=3;
    //final String PAUSE = "1";

    int temp,row;

    sPrefs = getSharedPreferences("storeData",MODE_PRIVATE);

    byte mode = (byte) sPrefs.getInt("Mode",1);
    byte [] pictureData = new byte [129];
    byte [] textSetting =new byte [5];


    if (socket == null) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        if(mode==TEXT_MODE){
            int l;
            textSetting[0]= 4;
            Thread.sleep(500);
            l = msg.getBytes().length;
            System.out.println("Length is "+ l);


            outputStream.write(textSetting);    
            outputStream.write(msg.getBytes());


        }
                                                //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        //outputStream.write(PAUSE.getBytes());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    list.add(new deviceListItem(msg, false));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    chatList.setSelection(list.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Theres a good thing going around on stack overflow. It talks about the minimal code to be able to reproduce your problem without the mess of all your code. Can you try to get a smaller amount of code behaving the same way that is easier on the eyes? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms - Sorry bout that. I've edited to show the main code that is involved.

Comment: so you are calling `sendMessageHandle(contentRow1.getText().toString());` but you want to print the length of `contentRow2` ????

Comment: @ScaryWombat - I have to `sendMessageHandle` - `sendMessageHandle(contentRow1.getText().toString()); and sendMessageHandle(contentRow2.getText().toString());` But with the getBytes(), I only know how to get the content of Row 1. How do I get the Row 2 length?

Comment: I really do not get what you are asking.  maybe English is not your native language and I appreciate that, but please try harder to explain.

Comment: `msg` is a string.  Assuming normal encoding `msg.getBytes().length == msg.length()`

Comment: @ScaryWombat - I have 2 EditText which is represented accordingly, Row 1 and Row 2. So for example, I type a string **"4567" in Row 1(EditText)** and **"567" in Row 2(EditText)**. Now when I use the command `msg.getBytes().length` and I do a `println` to see what the length is, I get **4**, which is basically the length of the Row 1 String(since it has 4 characters). But how do I get the length of the Row 2 also? Do I use `getBytes().length()` too ?

Comment: Once you pass a String into sendMessageHandle(String msg), there aren't any more **Row** s. You call once for **Row 1**, then again for **Row 2**, and so on. Thus, getBytes().length will be executed, once during the first call for **Row 1**, once during the 2nd call for **Row 2** and so on.

Comment: I am assuming Row1 == contentRow1 and Row2 == contentRow2.  You are calling `sendMessageHandle` with twice, one for each.  Nothing more needs to be done.  If it is not working correctly for contentRow2 then it is not corerctly bound to the editText like contentRow1 is.

Comment: @laune - Is there a way to obtain the length of it? So as it shows like `l = 4` and `k = 3` since `Row 1 has "4567"` and `Row 2 has "567"` So that one command `msg.getBytes()` will be executed as long as the SendMessageHandle is there?

@ScaryWombat - I'm very sure it is correctly assigned to like the contentRow1. I've checked numerous times for that. It keeps `println` **4** instead of like **4** then **3**

Comment: As far as I can see, you are sending these bytes in the call for **Row 1**: 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x30. (Why 4 and four times 0?) For the **Row 2**, you send again 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, followed by three bytes for "369". - Add println( ... '"' + msg + '"' ... ) to see the string that's passed to your method sendMessageHandle!

Comment: @laune - Apparently the 0 0 0 0 is caused by the `byte [] textSetting =new byte [5];` and `4` is because it is a Signal that I use to send to my microcontroller side to be able to display on a LED Panel.

When I tried to change to `byte [] textSetting =new byte [2];` it shows a 0x04 0x00 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x39

Mind elaborating on the + msg + ?

Comment: println( "Length is "+ l + ", msg=" + '"' + msg + '"' ) to see the string, not just the length.

Comment: @laune - Thanks. I had to put another parameter in the sendMessageHandle. Instead of sendMessageHandle(String msg), I had to put sendMessageHandle(String msg, String msg2). But now it returns me as a whole message like 4567369 instead of 4569 first then another line 369